# React-Typescript: I don't find the problem why my getCurrentTime Function won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to write a function to display the difference time between current time and e.g. the  creation time of a message. Herefore I wrote a function to get my current time before heading to the next step.

I intend to put the result into a table by `<td>{getCurrentTime}</td>`, but I cannot see any results of this function being displayed. There is not even a second column showing up.

```
import React from "react";

export function getCurrentTime () {
    let today = new Date();
    let dateTime = (today.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + ':' + (today.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + ':' + (today.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '');
    return dateTime;
}

//console.log(getCurrentTime);

export default getCurrentTime
```

this is where I want the time to be displayed:

```
const CommitMsgTable = ({ apiCommitsResponse }: CommitMsgTableProps) => {
let colorToggle = false;
return <div><table>{apiCommitsResponse.map(commit => {
    colorToggle = !colorToggle;
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{getCurrentTime}</td>
            <td style={{ backgroundColor: colorToggle ? "lightgrey" : "white" }}>                
                {commit}
            </td>
        </tr>)
})}
</table></div>
```

solved by tanmay and El Pandario!
I forgot the brackets () after calling {getCurrentTime} in the table data

Comment: I am getting not the time in my console but the function is working as intended. What do you want the function to display?

Comment: I want it to display the time in a table column. So I need the function to actually display the time when I refer to it in my code.

Comment: Ok, then you need to modify what you get from your ternary operator.
```
  let dateTime = (today.getHours() < 10 ? `0{today.getHours()}` : `${today.getHours()}`) + ':' + (today.getMinutes() < 10 ? `$0{today.getMinutes()}` : `${today.getMinutes()}`) + ':' + (today.getSeconds() < 10 ? `0${today.getSeconds()}` : `${today.getSeconds()}`);

```

Comment: `getCurrentTime` is a function right? you need to call it in your td tag.. like `<td>{getCurrentTime()}</td>`

Comment: Thanks alot tanmay, my problem is solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <tr>
        <td>Time: {getCurrentTime()}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  );
}

export function getCurrentTime () {
  let today = new Date();
  let dateTime = (today.getHours() < 10 ? `0${today.getHours()}` : `${today.getHours()}`) + ':' + (today.getMinutes() < 10 ? `0${today.getMinutes()}` : `${today.getMinutes()}`) + ':' + (today.getSeconds() < 10 ? `0${today.getSeconds()}` : `${today.getSeconds()}`);
  console.log(dateTime);
  return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: thank you! It was the missing brackets at getCurrentTime( )...

Comment: How can I add the word "Uhr" behind the seconds without my text to wrap? I can only make it work if I don't enter space between `${seconds}` : seconds}Uhr. I'd like to have a space character there though

Comment: If you put `` you can write text and put variables in it so you just add a space after ${seconds} and Uhr. `${seconds} : Uhr` should work.

Comment: The output is hh:mm:ss : Uhr, it displays the ":", too.

Comment: Then you remove the : in the `` and just put space and Uhr it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what you meant, but I think you wanted something like that:

```js
const getCurrentTime = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getSeconds();
    const timeString = `${hours.toString().length === 1 ? `0${hours}` : hours}:${minutes.toString().length === 1 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${seconds.toString().length === 1 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`;
    return timeString;
};

console.log(getCurrentTime())
```